# Is there a type which represents an object with any property but is no array

Tags: typescript

In other words I need a type which represents exactly the following conditions:

```js
batchObj !== null &&
typeof batchObj === "object" &&
Array.isArray(batchObj) === false
```

I used to use this type predicate function until I noticed that `{ [key: string]: any }` includes arrays:

```js
function isObject(obj: unknown): obj is { [key: string]: any } {
  return (
    obj !== null && typeof obj === "object" && Array.isArray(obj) === false
  );
}
```

This question is really harder to answer than I thought.

Comment: Try conditional types: ```T extends U ? X : Y``` . If type T can be resolved to U, then it will be assigned the type X, otherwise it will take type Y. I'm thinking that if T is resolveable to an array, you can change the type to something else. Maybe something like ```T extneds Array ? null : T``` will make the type go null if its an array, otherwise it wont change it. Ref: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript does not have true *negated types* like `not X` meaning "anything except `X`".  There is an experimental pull request at [microsoft/TypeScript#29317](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) where this is implemented, but it has not been and might never be merged into the main language.  So there's no *specific* type that maps completely to `object & not Array<any>`.

---

Instead there are various types of workarounds.  The simplest one I can think of is to come up with a specific type to which arrays are not assignable, but to which *most* other object types *are* assignable.  For example:

```
type NonArrayObject = object & { [k: string]: any; forEach?: undefined }
```

Here we are saying that a `NonArrayObject` must be a non-primitive (`object`), and which can any value for any `string` key, *except* that the property named `forEach` must either me *missing* or *`undefined`*.  This is pretty close to what you're looking for:

```
let nonArrayObject: NonArrayObject;
nonArrayObject = null; // error
nonArrayObject = "oops"; // error
nonArrayObject = {}; // okay
nonArrayObject = { a: 1, b: 2, c: "" }; // okay
nonArrayObject = [1, 2, 3]; // error
```

Of course, as a workaround, it's not perfect.  Maybe you really want to allow a *`forEach`* property?

```
nonArrayObject = { forEach: 123 }; // error!
```

Well, arrays have all sorts of methods and properties and maybe you can find one that you'd rather declare off limits.  Maybe `push`?

```
type NonArrayObject = object & { [k: string]: any; push?: undefined }
```

Or `lastIndexOf`?

```
type NonArrayObject = object & { [k: string]: any; lastIndexOf?: undefined }
```

No? you need to allow every possible key?  What if we allow `forEach` but require that it be a non-function (noting that `not Function` also doesn't exist)?

```
type NonArrayObject = object & {
  [k: string]: any;
  forEach?: undefined | string | number | boolean | null | { call?: never }
}
```

Et cetera, et cetera.  Pragmatically speaking, as long as you can identify *some* concrete "non-arraylike object" type, you can use it.  Personally I have never needed a non-array object with a `forEach` property so the original workaround would be the way I'd proceed.

This at least works for the `true` case of your type guard function:

```
declare function isObject(obj: unknown): obj is NonArrayObject;

const obj = Math.random() < 0.5 ? { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 } : [1, 2, 3];
if (isObject(obj)) {
  console.log(obj.b.toFixed(2)); // okay
}
```

---

A different workaround is to give up on specific types and instead use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) type. For example, you could use the following generic `isObject` definition which will behave as you expect, I think:

```
function isObject2<T>(obj: T | any[]): obj is T {
  return (
    obj !== null && typeof obj === "object" && Array.isArray(obj) === false
  );
}

if (isObject2(obj)) {
  console.log(obj.b.toFixed(2));
} else {
  console.log(obj.join(","));
}
```

That uses an inference from the union type `T | any[]` to `T` to implicitly remove `any[]` from the domain of the type.  Similarly:

```
function isObject3<T>(obj: T): obj is Exclude<T, any[]> {
  return (
    obj !== null && typeof obj === "object" && Array.isArray(obj) === false
  );
}

if (isObject3(obj)) {
  console.log(obj.b.toFixed(2));
} else {
  console.log(obj.join(","));
}
```

uses the [`Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) to explicitly remove `any[]` from the domain of the type.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gOwIICcUEMQHkBGArCAY2CgF4o58iSAyKAbwCgooBtAawC4oBnYFAJYIA5gF1u6BCADczKADM4KAKLpCACwD83AK4IAJhHlCI+xgF9GjADYQSCRKgzYqxbvGRpMuAsVkPPZx9qMigEHWtraSgAehioCDQlRgCnb1cScgAiODgwHizouISklBTHLxdfTIZzIvi4dkxywPTq0PoodG4ARgAaKBxuACYBwm4srKg62IamkBa0qpDyVn6oUagAZlF6kpRkxcrg4g6FJVUNXuGt6b3Eg5QAQit5PWIBRCgBHhPgAApKHhdAh2A4AO4IACU3CB3x4sAqQQyDDkKDsOhQCCg-zkLDhT1I5HCkSgNDooEgcHkFHwZCJUByGSm5KgSwAdD8loD8FD6eR5OhrDwIHIobJLIxCIg+LS8KEALLoYDqdkYAxwAC2-z5AB4oAAGdkAVigmgYXV6AyGGzG3Fu5ig3DWA02O1kAhp-x+fx5eChfKYLGlCB4cFs7OscGEfvZOHZwDgADEBAAPUz-YYB6IWV7vYCfbE+jLDXUAFQAfH7uGWoAAfLpSViiGFy+FQWtBqDo4CY7G4lj4umE4kRaxkingCDUttE7JA6gsugcrmVP18ucKIUisUSqyenHF6rDdeBuQhsMRqMxoFxhPJtMZrPiiwJYXQLsX8MQSPR2N4OAhH+LI+iybNczzBAPi+I9qC2csqyBGtWzhH4oGUVNCGsHRDHLAZJBAZsK1RFgez7HE8TbEcwjHCcoEpacaThTcmWqJc2UqTkeG5IENwZQV313CCD29X4Mi2U8SKgL8rz-W940TFN030TNwMdCB3ykmSf2vf9AIQYDQLUxggA)